# Where does Woocommerce store temporary cart data?

Tags: database, wordpress, session, woocommerce, cart

I need to hook into whatever unique ID Woocommerce uses to identify your session/cart while you're adding products but before you checkout. Does anyone know where to find that data in the database?

Anyone? Google is of zero help here.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce session is stored in `wp_woocommerce_sessions` table, inside `session_value` column as an array. Cart data is stored in `'cart'` key of this array.

If the user is **logged in**, the `session_key` column of this database table is **user ID**.

If the user is **logged out**, the `session_key` column of this database table is **session hash value**, which is stored as a cookie with `wp_woocommerce_session_*` key.

---

However if you somehow need to alter cart data when adding products to cart, you probably want to check out these hooks instead of modifying cart data directly in the database:

`woocommerce_add_cart_item_data`
`woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item`
`woocommerce_get_item_data`

Etc.

Comment: Really what I need to do is pass along meta data with the cart, so it shows up at the bottom of the receipt. I do this with PHP sessions now but for some reason it's losing data often. Was hoping at link it to this WP cart ID.

Comment: Okay I see where it is being updated. Is there a way to associate that session ID to the final order ID?